# GtkNotebook: Appending to the Default Popup Menu

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to append a menu item to the popup menu that appears by default on right-clicking a GtkNotebook's tab (the one that contains the names of all the open tabs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a somewhat gross hack, it *might* be possible to use [`gtk_notebook_get_menu_label()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-get-menu-label) to get the GtkLabel in one of the tab's menu items on that menu, and then use parent-walking from there to find the menu.

Possibly this only works when the menu is being realized/shown, you could try adding event handlers on that label to detect that.

On the other hand, [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056480/28169)'s suggestion of re-implementing the menu is way easier.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, it would appear that there is no way to append to the existing menu: the menu is kept in a private structure, and it is popped up directly on button-press event.

You can disable the default menu, connect to button-press event, and popup your own menu.